# Почему в данном случае не получается привязать контекст?

Tags: javascript

К сожалению, не могу продемонстрировать код в работе, так как здесь осуществляется работа с сервером с помощью `ajax`. Упрощенный пример.

Данный вариант работает:

```js
$('.form').submit(function() {

  var data = { /*...*/ };

  // Сработает в случае успеха
  var done = () => console.log(this); // <form></form>

  $.post(vus.ajaxurl, data, done);

  return false;
});
```

А этот вариант не работает:

```js
// Сработает в случае успеха
var done = () => console.log(this); // undefined

$('.form').submit(function() {

  var data = { /*...*/ };

  $.post(vus.ajaxurl, data, done.bind(this));

  return false;
});
```

Я не могу понять, почему? Я же создаю новую функцию, с помощью `bind` и привязываю контекст. 
Почему это не работает?

Comment: Потому что вы используете [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), а у них отсутствует контекст `this`, скорее всего, если вы опишите функцию как `var done = function(){...}` то все заработает.

Comment: А знаете, Вы правы! Сделайте это ответом, я отмечу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что  [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) не имеют контекста `this`.

Если переписать объявление функции done следующим образом, то должно заработать.

```
 var done = function(arg) {
     ...
 }
```